# Generating a list of dates based on one date

Tags: html, mysql, sql, cordova

I currently have a html form that will allow a user to enter a 'conception date' along with some additional information and click a 'start pregnancy' button.
The following is what I hope to achieve:
When the user clicks the 'start pregnancy' button, the conception date is used to generate a list of dates which are stored in a database.
Some of the dates I hope to generate include:

1. Ovulation Scan ( 2 days after Conception date / Conception date + 2)
2. Pregnancy Scan (16 days after Conception date / Conception date + 16)

I have tried creating an SQL statement but have yet to succeed at getting it to work.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DATE_ADD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function, like this:

```
SELECT now() AS ConceptionDate, 
DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) AS OvulationScan,
DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 16 DAY) AS PregnancyScan
```

You would be changing the `now()` part in the above query sample with the actual user selected date.

Comment: Hi Aziz, just wondering if you could tell me how I could take the user selected date and place it into the sql statement?

Comment: @user3037918 It depends on your frontend language, like PHP/.Net. Sorry I dont have much knowledge on those.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type) function

SELECT DATE_ADD(conception_date,INTERVAL 16 DAY)

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Comment: Thank you Aasimon, just what I was looking for